# how to invite people to events on our sharepoint calendar?

Tags: office-365, calendar

My company is using office 365.  They have a shared calendar on SharePoint where they post various events like meetings and social times.  The recruiters would like to be able to do two things.

1) invite new employees to these occurrences, so that they know when important team meetings are.

2) invite perspective employees to a *single* instance of one of these, to let them see what our company environment is like.

in addition they would like to have person A send out invites, but person B able to see who has accepted an invite.  Even better, if possible, would be if person B could get an automated notification when a certain minimum number of people accept invites.  She basically wants to know when perspective employees will be attending events, and how many, so she can make sure the appropriate people these perspective employees would want to meet will be in attendance.

This seems like a simple thing, but my understanding is that outlook and SharePoint do not integrate directly?  My question is, what is the simplest way to arrange for these features to work in a manner so that as much as possible will 'just work'.  Can I create a workflow for SharePoint to do something like this?

In my case we rarely add new events to the calendar, we are more interested in how to share existing events with new employees.

Comment: Are you using Outlook Client Software, or just the Web App of Outlook found in URL https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=yourcompany.com#path=/mail